# Difference between derivatives and limits?

Tags: calculus

Hey I have a small question - as I am getting into derivatives, I was shown how to take the limit as $h$ approaches $0$ and to create an equation. Additionally, we were told to never forget using the limit.

Then how come when we just have a function and we take the derivative of that function, we don‘t use limits?

Thanks in advance hopefully I could explain more or less what I mean....

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean "create an equation." You are always using limits, it's just hidden from you when you use derivative rules.

Comment: Oh I see, so essentially its there, we just don‘t write it out?

Comment: I suspect you misunderstood what you were told: "never forget using limits."

Comment: But since you haven't given any examples, not any exact statement you are understanding, it is really hard to answer.

Comment: Ehm.. okay so say we have the $f(x+h)-f(x)$ over $h$ right? In this case we would need to write $lim$ as $h -> 0$ then why don‘t we do that when taking derivatives of functions to create an equation.

Comment: Notation (in this case for dervative $f'(x)$) is often introduced to simplify writing mathematical expressions.  The *definition* of a derivative involves the limit of the difference quotient you just cited, and we shouldn't forget that limits are used to define derivatives.  But limits are used for many other things as well, such as power series and integrals.  So it's good to have a handle on the concept of taking limits, and if you go on in math you will find that it is a unifying concept in analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a real function $f$ is differentiable at point $a\in R$ if and only if f is defined on some open interval I containing a and $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ exists, in this case we call this limit the derivative of $f$ at $a$. So, the value of the derivative is a limit. The rules we use that apply to functions directly are just results that we have proven but everything goes back to the limit in the fundamental perspective. In addition, you could also see that there are some underlying assumptions that need to be satisfied for this definition to work ($f$ is defined on the open interval containing a, $a\in R$,etc..) This means when you apply the rules, you must also be aware of the assumptions, although definitions and rules could vary(consider one side derivatives), the fundamentals don't change.

Answer (score 5):

The derivative is *by definition* the limit $$f'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.$$ So for example, if $f(x) = x^2$ then $f'(x) = 2x$ means exactly that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = 2x.$$  You wouldn't write something like $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} f'(x) = 2x$$ because that would mean $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = 2x$$ which doesn't make sense.

To *prove* that $f'(x) = 2x$ you do need to show that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = 2x.$$ But once you know this, you don't have to write out the limit every time.  That's the power of notation.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a function $f$ at $x$, defined as $f'(x)$ is supposed to provide the  $ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$. The limit is also supposed to exist however $h$ chooses to approach $0$. By the rules we derived, we are able to write down these limits. E.g. the chain rule.